# Duplicate Filemaker Record and related Portal Records

Tags: database, filemaker

I'm a Filemaker noob, so I need to put that right out there.

I have a table (Gigs) and related portal table (Gigs_Join) where a list of songs is shown in the portal. These are connected via GigID in the main and portal tables.

I want to duplicate a Gig record and all related portal records. I know this has to be scripted, but for my life, I can't make it work.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: This question is better suited to one of the forums dedicated to the Filemaker platform. If the answer I provided [here](https://community.filemaker.com/thread/196225)  is not satisfactory, pursue the subject further there.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try these steps,
1. Create two Table Occurrences GigsJoin1, GigsJoin2 based on Gigs_Join
2. Create two layouts (GigsJoin1, GigsJoin2) based on above TOs.

3. Write a script with following Steps.
    a. Go to Gigs layout.
    b. Save the Gig ID in a variable (OrigGigID).
    c. Duplicate the Gig record.
    d. Save the new Gig ID in a variable (NewGigID).
    e. Go to the layout GigsJoin1.
    f. Find the records using OrigGigID.
    g. Start Loop
        i. Go to first record
        ii. Copy all the field values in variables.
        iii. Go to layout GigsJoin2.
        iv. Create new record
        v. Set the values from variables.
        vi. Set the GigsID from variable NewGigID
        vii. Go to Layout GigsJoin1
        viii. Go to next record
    e. End Loop
```

Comment: There is no need to add anything to the schema in order to duplicate data.

Comment: He needs a way to keep the found set of related records of original gig and also create new related records for duplicated gig. There may be several workarounds like looping portal, creating records using magic key, etc... But this is easier and straight forward way.

Comment: See: https://community.filemaker.com/message/842675?commentID=842675#comment-842667